# AngularJS and GitHub Pages - loading templates issue

Tags: angularjs, github-pages, angular-routing

I'm trying to set up [my Angular app](https://github.com/moroshko/seekdeck/tree/gh-pages) on GitHub pages at http://moroshko.github.io/seekdeck.

The Angular routes are defined in `application.js`:

```
<html ng-app="SeekDeck">
  <head>
    ...
    <script src="scripts/application.js"></script>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-view></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

`application.js` is loaded from `/seekdeck/scripts`, as expected.

My app routes look like this:

```
// Part of application.js
$routeProvider
  .when("/", {
    templateUrl: "templates/dashboard/dashboard.html",
    ...
  })
  ...
```

When Angular tries to get the `dashboard.html` template, it tries to load it from `/templates/dashboard` rather than `/seekdeck/templates/dashboard`, and therefore it cannot find it.

Any ideas why is this happening, or how could I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because angular is expecting that url to be relative to the root of the domain, not to the location of your app. In other words, it is expecting it to be relative to `moroshko.github.io` not `moroshko.github.io/seekdeck`.

You can solve this easily by adding a `base` element to your html page, and setting its `href` attribute to the path you want the root of your app to be (in your case `/seekdeck/`)

Put the following tag inside the `<head>` of your html page:

```
<base href="/seekdeck/" />
```

Also make sure you are setting `html5mode(true)` in `$locationProvider`.

There's an excellent blog post about it [**HERE**](http://www.verdantrefuge.com/writing/2013/angularjs-changing-app-path-base-element/)